# Как обойти Fatal Error Через try-catch?

Tags: php

```
class Foo{

}
$obj=new Foo;
try{
    $obj->getPar();
}  catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exeption';
}
echo 'Hello World';
```

Хочется отловить ошибку и продолжить дальше исполнение кода...
Почему нету похожего механизма как у javascript?Ошибка-будь добр делай дальше..Тогда зачем было такой механизм вводить ?
Stackoverflow пишет что нужно использовать проверки существования класса/метода.

Comment: В каждом языке программирования существует механизм, который предотвращает исполнение кода, если возникает ошибка "несовместимая с жизнью". В компилируемых языках Вам бы вообще не удалось вызвать несуществующую функцию, так как компилятор бы выдал ошибку, как например в Java, Objective-C. В РНР сделали вот так вот. И это правильно. Вообще все эти Exceptions, если научиться с ними работать - замечательная штука!

Comment: Добавлю, что такой механизм предотвращает практически неотлавливаемые ошибки: если бы вызов несуществующего метода _можно_ было бы тупо игнорировать, и вы допустили в названии метода опечатку, то вы никогда бы об этом не узнали, и ваш код просто неправильно себя вёл бы.

Чем больше фигни запрещено, тем лучше.

Comment: механизм введен чтобы обрабатывать исключения типа [throw](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/internals2.opcodes.throw.php)

Comment: Хорошо.Тогда чем if() хуже exeption?Не вижу случая когда нельзя эмулировать Exeption обычным циклом с проверками.

Comment: например когда ваш объект должен сообщить программе его вызвавшей об ошибке, приведщей к остановке выполнения метода, т.е. когда необработанная ошибка должна считаться фатальной. эмулировать то можно, но тогда каждый будет собственным способом сообщать об ошибке, а так **все договорились** что можно кидать exeption. А вообще многие конструкции в языках сделаны просто для удобства, ведь можно же `for` эмулировать через while, a foreach через array_keys, только немного неудобно.